# Extend core modernizr library

Tags: 8

I am noticing `objectFit` is not part of Drupal 8 `core/modernizr` library. How do I add `objectFit` detection without overriding core modernizr?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to override core/modernizr with a later version in order to get objectFit.

1. [Download an updated modernizr.js](https://modernizr.com/download) and include objectFit.
2. Place the file somewhere in your theme's path (js/ or scripts/)
3. In your theme's info file (*theme-name*.info.yml) , override the existing modernizr library

```
libraries-override:   
  core/modernizr:
    js:
      assets/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.min.js: scripts/modernizr.js
```

You should now have access to objectFit.